# How to get exact search result using MYSQL LIKE operator

Tags: mysql

We have search functionality in our application but problem is that when i searched for term like "**pen**" it show result from word **open** in open word there is name pen but we don't want to show such result. we want to show result like **xyz pen xyz**. we used **my sql LIKE in query**  
So how to achieve this using MY-SQL LIKE?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: What if your data starts with **pen**? Then there is no space at the begining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you want to find results that contain a word "pen" or any other specified (the title suggests that the whole result should look exactly like the term).

`LIKE` is too simple to do that, you need to use `RLIKE` with *word boundaries*.
`[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` are special markers that indicate *word start* and *word end* respectively, so instead of:

`LIKE '%pen%'`

use:

`RLIKE '[[:<:]]pen[[:>:]]'`

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name LIKE "% pen %";
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your behavier then you can use:

```
columnName like '% pen %'
```

Answer (score -1):

Select * from table where name like 'pen';

"name" is column name for searching.

Comment: Can you find `pen` from this `xyz pen xyz`  using your query?